# Jsrender.js fails when I add bootstrap-tag.js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsrender, bootstrap-tags-input

I added these js:

```
    <script src="js/jsrender.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-tag.min.js"></script>
```

And I have this template:

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-jsrender">
        <tr class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr" tabindex="-1" id="filaAgregada" role="row" aria-selected="false">
        <td aria-describedby="grid-table_cb" style="text-align:center;width: 25px;" role="gridcell"><input type="checkbox" name="jqg_grid-table_1" class="cbox" id="jqg_grid-table_1" role="checkbox"></td>
        <td aria-describedby="grid-table_id" role="gridcell">{{:numero}}</td>
        <td aria-describedby="grid-table_evento" role="gridcell"><input class="form-control, form-field-tags" type="text" name="evento"></td>
        <td aria-describedby="grid-table_efnc" role="gridcell"><input class="form-control, form-field-tags" type="text" name="eventosFNC"></td>
        <td aria-describedby="grid-table_efc" role="gridcell"><input class="form-control, form-field-tags" type="text" name="eventosFC"></td>
        <td aria-describedby="grid-table_condicion" role="gridcell"><input class="form-control, form-field-tags" type="text" name="eventosCondiciones"></td>
        <td aria-describedby="grid-table_datoAsociado" role="gridcell"><input class="form-control, form-field-tags" type="text" name="eventoDatosAsociados"></td>
        <td aria-describedby="grid-table_TEF" role="gridcell"><input class="form-control, form-field-tags" type="text" name="eventoTEFEaE"></td>
        </tr>
</script>
```

When I do this:

```
$("#bodyTablaEventos").append($("#template").render(contador));
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: b.props is undefined
>   jsrender.min.js Line 3

If I delete `<script src="js/bootstrap-tag.min.js"></script>`, jsrender works fine.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bootstrap-tag is adding a `.tag()` method to jQuery instances, which is causing an error in JsRender. I'll fix it for the next update of JsRender, to avoid the collision. But meantime, you can use the preferred syntax for rendering JsRender templates:

`var tmpl = $("#template");
$("#bodyTablaEventos").html(tmpl.render(contador));
//or
$("#bodyTablaEventos").append(tmpl.render(contador));`

With that syntax there should be no conflict... (See [The template.render() method](http://www.jsviews.com/#tmplrender)).

You can also use [$.render.myTmpl()](http://www.jsviews.com/#d.render)

Comment: The latest version of JsRender fixes the above collision, so the original syntax should now work fine too. (http://www.jsviews.com/#download or https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender)